# migrating severs with MySQL database and treating null values differently

Tags: php, mysql

I'm transferring a MySQL database & website from one server to another. I'm getting errors with myslqi insert statements where I have a column that is not explicitly defined in the code and in the database it's inserting null.

In the old database, it would insert '0' instead of null when the value wasn't explicitly set and null wasn't allowed and the type was INT.

This has lead to some lazy coding where these values haven't been defined. Is this a database setting I can set to change this default behavior as an interim measure as I have lots of code to review to ensure all these instances are corrected?

Comment: You can set in the table definition, what value is going to be used as default. But, TBH, I would nuke that entire codebase (or at least - persistence layer). If you are having such issues, you are probably also suffering from a widespread SQL injection issue.

Comment: Did you upgrade MySQL versions? You may need to change some global SQL mode settings so that you get the same behavior as before.

Comment: @Barmar I suspect this is what happened. Where do I make those global SQL setting changes?

Comment: In the `my.cnf` file for the server.